# onClick in appended element so slow when run on Android

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have built phonegap app, and i am new with phonegap and jquery mobile. When i clicked on appended element in browser, it works well but when i run on Android, it is so slow to respond. 
this is my function code

```
function LoadAcara()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/viewacara.php',
        data: { "id": user},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status){

            $.each(data, function(i,item){

            if(item.cekfol=="ya")
            {
                if (first)
                {   
                        if (arrID.indexOf(item.idacara)<0)
                        {   

                            $('#daftaracara').append('<li><img id="gambar" onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')" src="web/'+item.gambar+'" alt=""><h2>'+item.nama+'</h2>'+'<p style="font-size:15px; color:#333366;">Tanggal : '+item.tanggal+'</p><p style="font-size:14px; color:#00F;">Lokasi : '+item.lokasi+'</p><a data-role="button" class=" ui-btn-b followButton" data-theme="b" onclick="simpanacara('+item.idacara+')">Following</a></li>').trigger('create'); 
                            arrID.push(item.idacara);

                        }

                    first=false;
                }
                else {
                        if (arrID.indexOf(item.idacara)<0)
                        {
                            $('#daftaracara').prepend('<li><img id="gambar" onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')" src="web/'+item.gambar+'" alt=""><h2>'+item.nama+'</h2>'+'<p style="font-size:15px; color:#333366;">Tanggal : '+item.tanggal+'</p><p style="font-size:14px; color:#00F;">Lokasi : '+item.lokasi+'</p><a data-role="button" class=" ui-btn-b followButton" data-theme="b" onclick="simpanacara('+item.idacara+')">Following</a></li>').trigger('create');    
                            arrID.push(item.idacara);
                        }
                }
                $('ul').collapsibleset();
            }
            else if(item.cekfol=="tidak")
            {
                if (first)
                {

                        if (arrID.indexOf(item.idacara)<0)
                        {   

                            $('#daftaracara').append('<li><img id="gambar" onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')" src="web/'+item.gambar+'" alt=""><h2>'+item.nama+'</h2>'+'<p style="font-size:15px; color:#333366;">Tanggal : '+item.tanggal+'</p><p style="font-size:14px; color:#00F;">Lokasi : '+item.lokasi+'</p><a data-role="button" class=" ui-btn-b followButton" data-theme="b" onclick="simpanacara('+item.idacara+')">Follow</a></li>').trigger('create');    
                            arrID.push(item.idacara);

                        }

                    first=false;
                }
                else {
                        if (arrID.indexOf(item.idacara)<0)
                        {
                            $('#daftaracara').prepend('<li><img id="gambar" onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')" onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')" src="web/'+item.gambar+'" alt=""><h2>'+item.nama+'</h2>'+'<p style="font-size:15px; color:#333366;">Tanggal : '+item.tanggal+'</p><p style="font-size:14px; color:#00F;">Lokasi : '+item.lokasi+'</p><a data-role="button" class=" ui-btn-b followButton" data-theme="b" onclick="simpanacara('+item.idacara+')">Follow</a></li>').trigger('create');   
                            arrID.push(item.idacara);
                        }
                }
                $('ul').collapsibleset();
            }

            });

        },
        error: function(){
            //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    })

}
```

and this is for call function LoadAcara()

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     LoadAcara();
     setInterval(function () {LoadAcara(), 1000});
});
```

Comment: What version of Android is the device/emulator running? Devices older than Android 4.4 are known to have WebView issues!

Comment: i am using Android device and kitkat version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function under onDeviceReady(), like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     LoadAcara();
     setInterval(function () {LoadAcara(), 1000});
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Mobile, onclick function has a little delay for mobile devices.

vclick event has no delay, if you don't want the delay try changing it. Here is the documentation about vclick: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/